# Add Slidein Transition Effect for Image When img src Changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an img tag in .HTML file like below:

```
<img id="xyz"/>
```

In javascript, I have code like the below:

```
let i = 1;
let images = ["src1", "src2", "src3", "src4", "src5"];

let imgDiv = document.getElementById('xyz');
imgDiv.src = images[0];

setInterval(() => {
    momentDiv.src = images[i];
    i++;
    if(i == images.length) i=0;
}, 5000);
```

I image in imgDiv is switching every 5 seconds.

How to give animation or transition to the image whenever "src" property changes?

No jQuery please.

Comment: You can wrap your images with a div and then scroll the div using javascript

Comment: @HaiAlaluf I need to have only one img tag. Having multiple img tags is not an option.

Comment: You can use `transform: matrix` and `transition` but you wont be able to use the same img tag so I am not sure if it helps

Comment: You need to copy image dom node for sliding to work i guess

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it like you want.

To make a slide effect, you need at least 2 images.
So you need to update the src of your second image and move this image above your first one. Then your second image should become first (the src of second image you need to copy to the old image tag and repeat the algorytm)

```js
let i = 1;
let images = ["https://picsum.photos/200/200/?image=663", "https://picsum.photos/200/200/?image=662", "https://picsum.photos/200/200/?image=661", "https://picsum.photos/200/200/?image=660", "https://picsum.photos/200/200/?image=659"];

let imgDiv = document.getElementById('xyz');
let imgSecond = document.getElementById('zyx');

imgDiv.src = images[0];

setInterval(() => {
    imgSecond.src = images[i];
    imgSecond.classList.add('active');
    i++;
    if(i == images.length) i=0;
  
    setTimeout(function() {
      imgDiv.src = imgSecond.src;
      imgSecond.classList.remove('active');
    }, 1500); // the same time as transition animation at css.
}, 2000);
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrap > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrap > img#zyx {
  top: 200px;
}
.wrap > img#zyx.active {
  top: 0;
  transition: top 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img id="xyz" width="200" height="200"/>
  <img id="zyx" width="200" height="200"/>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody still need how to do it in easy way (excample fade in and out effect - you can add other effect too)

```
let images = ["img1_url","img2_url", "img3_url", "img4_url"];

$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("#id_of_the_img_element").attr("src", images[i]);
    setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        if (i == images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        $("#id_of_the_img_element").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).attr("src", images[i]);
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```